# Datacenter simulation in ns2

Tags: simulation, network-protocols, ns2

Ok, I am not sure about this question so sorry in advance if I am wrong putting it here. So I want to create a simulation of a data center using ns2 where I will compare different protocols in 2 metrics.

I am reading the tutorial for ns2 and found some extra material on the Internet and I found some papers to also read that might give me an insight on how to go about simulations (though from a first overview I don't think so) but I would like to know if anyone can direct me towards with more solid examples with some explanations if possible in more complex networks (prefereably data centers)

The ns2 tutorial only covers the basics. I know that I will have to decide before hand what topology to use for my data center (I am currently between a typical 3 layer data center topology and BCube, mainly because I am curious about a certain topology benefiting a specific protocol but not making a difference in another). Based on that I will have to build it in the tcl files. Then I know that somehow I will have to feed it a workload which I assume is a schedule of action simulating traffic but I am not clear on how this is done. In the tutorial they only have the "at" cases which are pretty straightforward but don't see a way to help me in my case. I assume I will also have to maybe set the routing scheme but...

So this is what I have on my head so far. Clearly, I am little lost so any help would be appreciated. Papers with similar things, essays or descriptions of projects, tutorials...

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate ns2 with **green cloud Simulator** to create data center. Already in green cloud package they have given some example tcl for the same.